# Installing driver for RTL8192EU problem

Tags: drivers, kernel

Trying to install from instructions on: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver and I get:

```
$ kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~/Downloads/rtl8192EU_linux_v4.3.1.1_11320.20140505$
 sudo dkms add
Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: add <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module> -v <module-version>
```

How to do correctly `sudo dkms add`?

I tried also:

```
kirby @kirby -Aspire-ES1- 433
sudo add-apt-repository ppa hanipouspilot/rtlwifi   
[sudo] password for kirby
```

This is ppa for Realtek drivers from Larry Finger's GitHub.

```
  rtl8192eu is packaged from the Realtek site with some compat patches
  . More info
  : https
  : //launchpad
  . net /~hanipouspilot/ + archive /ubuntu/ rtlwifi Press [ENTER] to continue
  or Ctrl -c to cancel adding it.

  Hit:1 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease Ign  
  Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
  Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [ 83, 2 kB ]     
  Hit:4 http:// hr . archive . ubuntu . com / ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease   
  Hit:5 http:// hr . archive . ubuntu . com / ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease Err
  : 6 http
  : //ppa
  . launchpad
  . net /hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/
  ubuntu bionic Release 404 Not Found [ IP : 91.189.95.83 80 ] Get
  : 7 http
  : //security
  . ubuntu
  . com / ubuntu bionic-security / main amd64 DEP-
  11 Metadata [ 204 B ]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2 452 B]
Reading package lists... Done                   
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:4 http://hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/hanipouspilot/rtlwifi/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package rtl8192eu-dkms
```

What is wrong?

Comment: yes,  . is included

Comment: @Kirby-1989 do `sudo apt update` before your `sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms`, it can't work if you don't update your command DB; and for `sudo dkms add`, you just have to read, it needs an other argument (i suppose it can be `rtl8192eu`)

Comment: do not know  how to solve this : 
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ sudo dkms rtl8192eu add
Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: add <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module> -v <module-version>
kirby@kirby-Aspire-ES1-433:~$

Comment: You run a wrong command. ` sudo dkms rtl8192eu add` is wrong. Where did you get it?

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 1):

The step by step guide is

```
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms add .
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Comment: tnxs  this code worked well!